# YQL does not return an xpath select query with a union operator (a|b) in document order

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, yql

My first attempt at XPath - I'm struggling to find an XPath condition for a YQL select query that outputs **in sequence** different sibling elements from an HTML page.  I can get all the individual elements, each in its own sequence (so `<p1>, <p2>, <p3>` and `<ul1>, <ul2>, <ul3>`, etc), but not in the sequence they are encountered in the source HTML document - say, `<p1> <ul1> <ul2> <ul3> <p2> <p3>`.

My current 'best fit' is:

`select * from html WHERE url = "URL of web page" AND xpath = "//div[@class = \'div class\']/p | //div[@class = \'div class\']/ul"`

Which translates to the XPath:

```
//div[@class = 'div class']/p | //div[@class = 'div class']/ul
```

I can easily enough get the lot as text with something like `//div[@class = 'div class']/text()`, but then I lose the formatting.  Is there some way to get YQL to maintain the sequence of selected, different elements?  Or have I just completely misunderstood how XPath works?

EDIT: Sample HTML structure:

```
<div class = "class">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Following is a list:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Still more text</p>
</div>
```

My current XPath code (above) returns the `<p>` elements and the `<ul>` element separately, and while the `<p>` elements are in sequence, there is no way to determine exactly where the `<ul>` element is (it can vary from one page to another).  As a result, I can't reconstruct the HTML from the XPath.  If I use `/text()`, the full text is returned, in order from top to bottom, but there is no formatting (the `<p>` and `<ul>` tags are ignored) - just a single line of text with no spaces between the individual elements.  If the `<ul>` tag was inside `<p>` tags (a descendant rather than sibling), there would not be a problem.  The issue only exists with sibling elements of different types.

To replicate the behavior I am seeing, I used the following:

```
SELECT * FROM html 
   WHERE url = "http://www.smh.com.au/sport/soccer/matildas-fuming-after-ffa-rejects-paid-mater‌​nity-leave-proposal-20150911-gjkq81.html" 
   AND xpath = "//div[@class = 'articleBody']/*[self::ul or self::p]"
```

Comment: Can you show an (indented and correct) fragment of the HTML you are trying to query? I can't make out the parent/child/sibling relationships from your `<p>` and `<ul>` examples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit with answer from your comment:

you may be viewing the result as something other than XML. For instance, if you view it as JSON, that format does not have a predefined order for maps. If you were to view it as XML, the order should be as expected.

---

#### Original answer, leaving it in for reference:

> My current XPath code (above) returns the `<p>` elements and the `<ul>` element separately

I believe this to be a bug in the XPath engine the [yql](/questions/tagged/yql) is using. The XPath language, any version of it, clearly states that the elements must be returned in document order after combining the set with the union operator `|`, which is typically the same as the order in which they appear in the XML<sup>1</sup>.

You may try to fix this buggy behavior by using the following XPath, which *first* selects all children and *then* filters:

```
//div[@class = 'div class']/*[self::p or self::ul]
```

It is also easier to read, I think.

Note: you do not need to escape single quotes with `\'` if you quote the string with double quotes.

<sup>1</sup> *Namespace and attribute nodes have no order, but there order must be stable, that is, two calls selecting the same nodes will return them in the same order.*

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.  I had actually tried exactly your solution (without really knowing exactly what it was doing), but the result is the same.  In the YQL console, when I run this XPath, there are still separate 'p' and 'ul' results.  If its a YQL bug, I may need to look for a different solution.

Comment: @sideroxylon, it is also possible that the YQL console simply orders them alphabetically, meaning that it processes the XPath correctly, but just displays them by another order?

Comment: @sideroxylon, if you have a link to your YQL console for your test, maybe I can try see what's happening?

Comment: I think I have found the problem.  If you view the results in the YQL console in xml format, they are in order.  I have been requesting the results as JSON.  You can see the difference if you load this in the YQL console:  `select * from html WHERE url = "http://www.smh.com.au/sport/soccer/matildas-fuming-after-ffa-rejects-paid-maternity-leave-proposal-20150911-gjkq81.html" AND xpath = "//div[@class = 'articleBody']/*[self::ul or self::p]"`.  Looks like I'm going to have to learn how to deal with xml.  :)  Thanks.  I'll give you the points because you explained what was happening.

Comment: @sideroxylon, thanks, I have updated my answer (and your q.) to reflect this.